# Vuex in localstorage weird behavio

Tags: local-storage, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm developing a webapp with Nuxt.js and I'm using vuex and vuex-persisteddate to save a store to localstorage. Everything worked fine apart of a thing: on the boot of the app, if i log something from vuex which is stored in the localstorage, I tried many things and I come up with this:

```js
this.$nextTick(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (!this.$store.getters['temp/isCacheUp2Date']) {
          this.loadData()
        }
    }, 0)
})
```

As this it works but I don't understand why I need a timeout to 0 to make it work and why if i remove the setTimeout it doesn't work (if i log something from vuex it prints the default value, written in the file by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Becaus localstorage is on your browser, and thats client side. if you try to get items out of it it wont work.

instead of this nextTicks or setTimeout you could simply do this:

```
if(process.browser){
   //execute code on browser
}
```